# chown a folder on host with a user that only exists inside a docker container

Tags: filesystems, mount, docker, chown

So, basically, I have a docker container running and i have mounted a host file-system inside the container so that the processes inside can have access to its files. The running process inside the docker container requires the files in the mounted file-system to be its ownership but they have a different owner (my host user). Whenever i try to change the ownership from my host to that of the container, chown reports an invalid user error.

```
$ sudo chown -R odoo:odoo *
chown: invalid user: ‘odoo:odoo’
```

Is is possible to chown the files from the host using a non-existent user ? Or there's another way how to do things ? 
By the way, the mounted folder contains additional modules that the process needs. I am developing those modules on my host machine and then testing them directly using docker without having to copy them again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the UID number rather than a name. For example, if `odoo` has UID 1023 and GID 475 then you can use those numbers directly:

```
sudo chown -R 1023:475 *
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. Do you know why Linux doesn't accept usernames but accepts UIDs and GIDs ?

Comment: It doesn't know about them - they're local to your Docker instance.

Comment: In the container it says `nodbody` and `nogroup` for me and wont let me write to the files/directory (using `ls -l`)

Comment: Hello @TheFloatingBrain, that sounds like it may be a different issue. You can ask a new question, and if you think this question/answer is relevant by all means reference it in your question

Comment: @ChrisDavies Actually I already did haha https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/760914/cant-get-container-to-mount-volume-with-standard-user