# Cant Get Container To Mount Volume With Standard User

Tags: permissions, container, podman, volume

I can't seem to get containers (running `podman`) to be able to write to directories when running a standard user. [This solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580339/how-to-grant-read-write-access-through-selinux-policy-to-a-bind-mounted-volume-v) also did not work.
To be clear I can read files from these directories, I just cant write to or create them.

`z`, `Z` on the volume does not seem to make it work. I have gotten it to work with a root using chcon, but I have tried adding new policy modules, permissive scopes, permissive mode etc.

I think it some sort of permissions error. The folder in the container (in naive case at least) seems be owned by `root` and has "group" `nogroup` I don't know if that is standard or not.

I have tried `chown`ing (like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451483/chown-a-folder-on-host-with-a-user-that-only-exists-inside-a-docker-container)) the directory to the container user id and/or group id (in which case it can be owned by `nobody` and `nogroup` (does not work). I have also logged into the container with the host user+group id (it recognized my username in the bash terminal) -- no difference. Also some combination of these with `chown`ing the folder to different users/groups such as the host user/group, container user/group, root user/group (a bit ambiguous container/host root), etc.

Here are some sample outputs from `ls -lnZ` from in and outside the container on a few test files (note I changed the user id's except for `65534` as [apparently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/720557/what-is-the-id-of-nobody-user-and-nogroup-group) this is a special id reserved for `nobody`.
The id of the ***host user*** is `9876` and id of the ***container user*** is `1234`. I checked with `id -u` to ensure the actual user id's corresponded to these. Small note, in this case the host group id is different, so lets say `5432`, while the group id of the container user would be `1234`

test5:

- container:

  ```
  drwxr-xr-x. 2 0 65534 system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0 4096 Nov  7 23:50 test
  ```
- host:

  ```
  drwxr-xr-x. 2 9876 9876 system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0             4096 Nov  7 18:50 test5
  ```

test4:

- container:

  ```
  drwxr-xr-x. 2 0 65534 system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0 4096 Nov  8 02:59 test
  ```
- host:

  ```
  drwxr-xr-x. 2 9876 1234 system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0             4096 Nov  7 21:59 test4
  ```

test3:

- container:

  ```
  drwxr-xr-x. 2 0 65534 system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0 4096 Nov  7 21:40 test
  ```
- host before:

  ```
  drwxr-xr-x. 2 9876 1234 system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0:c1022,c1023 4096 Nov  7 16:40 test3
  ```
- host after:

  ```
  drwxr-xr-x. 2 9876 1234 system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0 4096 Nov  7 16:40 test3
  ```

If I fix the group id for test5, still does not work:

test5 (again):

- container:

  ```
  drwxr-xr-x. 2 0 0 system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0 4096 Nov  7 23:50 test
  ```
- host:

  ```
  drwxr-xr-x. 2 9876 5432 system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0 4096 Nov  7 18:50 test5
  ```

What problem might I be having writing/creating files in mounted volumes in a container as a standard user, and how can I make the standard user create/write files in mounted directories properly without resorting to very insecure solutions?

Comment: Bear in mind that owners/groups outside the container may have different names to those inside the container. Best is to use UID/GID numbers. Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/760914/edit) to show `ls -ln` for (some of) the affected files and/or directories and say whether this is from inside or outside the container. Also identify the UID (number) for the container process/owner (`id -u`)

Comment: @ChrisDavies Edited!